# Drools rule is running then clause multiply times

Tags: drools

I have just started learning Drools and have written the following rule

```
rule "matematikk"
 when
  class( code == "MAT1003") or class( code == "MAT1008")
  or
  class( code == "REA3022") or class( code == "REA3024") or class( code == "REA3026") or class( code == "REA3028")
  or
  class(code == "MAT1006") and class(code == "MAT1010") or class( code == "MAT1001") and class( code == "MAT1005")
  or
  class(code == "MAT1002") or class(code == "MAT1007")
then
  logger.info("passed");
end
```

when I run this rule I will get three passed prints in the terminal? which is correct since only three of the line are true, but how do I make it process the entire "when" block and after that go to the "then" section.

cheers,

ehsan

also if I remove the "or" between the lines I won't get any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule doesn't really make sense. You've got "ands" and "ors" mixed up in here in no particular order. Setting things on separate lines doesn't create any sort of "grouping". Proximity similarly doesn't provide any sort of inherent relationship. The "and"s on the third 'line' are particularly confusing -- I have no idea what they're supposed to be and-ing.

Generally, if you want to represent an "or" condition, you'd write the conditional like this:

```
class( code in ("MAT1003", "MAT1008", ... ))
```

(Where "..." represents additional values.)

This is read as "There is a 'class' that has code *MAT1003* or *MAT1008*."

For an "and" you'd simply have two different statements; only if both match will the rule be 'triggered'. For example:

```
exists(class(code == "MAT1006"))
exists(class(code == "MAT1010"))
```

This would trigger if there are at least 2 "class" instances in working memory, and there is at least one with code *MAT1006* and at least one with code *MAT1010*.

I used `exists` because you don't actually need a reference to the matching instance for use in the right hand side; I also presumed you only need to trigger once regardless of how many instances matched your condition.

---

Finally -- I **strongly** suggest not naming your class "class" since it's a reserved word in Java. If it is representing some sort of educational class (eg at university), may I suggest calling it Course instead?